# laravel upload image return mime-type application/octet-stream

Tags: php, laravel, oop

My upload is not working even image validation returns false so I disabled it

when i dd() image   mimeType: "application/octet-stream"

http://prntscr.com/qks9ly

HTML

```
          {!! Form::open(['url'=>adminUrl('enrichments'),'files' => true]) !!}



          <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">{{ trans('admin.img') }}</label>
              <input id="input-folder-5" name="img" type="file" class="form-control" >
          </div>

          <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">

              <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input type="radio" name="active" id="option2" value="0" autocomplete="off"> {{ trans('admin.noActvided') }}
              </label>
              <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
                <input type="radio" name="active" id="option1" value="1" autocomplete="off" checked> {{ trans('admin.actvided') }}
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          {!! Form::submit(trans('admin.send'),['class'=>'btn btn-primary ']) !!}
          {!! Form::close() !!}
```

PHP ini

```
upload_max_filesize = 120M
post_max_size = 120M
```

My Controller

```
request()->file('img')->store('enrichments');
```

Comment: php artisan storage:link do you call command

Comment: @dılosürücü i did